# MongoDB: returning titles that have multiple copies

Tags: mongodb

So I have, more or less, this collection, times, like, 1800:

```
uniqueid1, Title 1, Copy 1
uniqueid2, Title 1, Copy 1
uniqueid3, Title 2, Copy 1
uniqueid4, Title 2, Copy 2
uniqueid5, Title 3, Copy 1
uniqueid6, Title 4, Copy 1
```

(In case it's not obvious, the "uniqueid" field is the primary key.)

I want to return the results for all Titles that have more than one Copy 1. So basically, the only Title that would get returned from the dataset above is Title 1 (because Title 2 has distinct Copy numbers and Titles 3 and 4 only have 1 Copy each).

My instincts are telling me that this is an aggregate type of thing. But I can't quite figure it out. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!
inger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is quiet simple:

1. `$group` the records by the `title` and the `copy` together.
2. For each unique combination of the title and copy(a group), we get
   the `count` of total number of records in that group, using the `$sum` operator.
3. Groups with `count value > 1` are the groups we want.
4. Then we `$project` the `title` of those groups.

Here goes the pipeline:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
 {$group:{"_id":{"title":"$title","copy":"$copy"},"count":{$sum:1},"title":{$first:"$title"}}},
 {$match:{"count":{$gt:1}}},
 {$project:{"title":1,"_id":0}}
 ])
```

Comment: This gets me going in the right direction! Thanks again.